# Symfony form validation error with customType ManyToMany

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm running Symfony 3.3 with a form type configuration like this.

```
class UserFinancialTransactionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('billingAddresses', AddressType::class, array(
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        ));
    }
}

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $countryChoices = $options['country_choices'];
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.first_name',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.last_name',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('line1', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.line1',
            ))
            ->add('line2', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.line2'
            ))
            ->add('city', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.city'
            ))
            ->add('postalCode', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.postal_code'
            ))
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.country',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
                'choices' => $countryChoices,
                'choice_label' => 'shortDe',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.shortDe', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Address::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'country_choices' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

BillingAddresses is a child of user (many-to-many-relation). In my form I want to have only one BillingAddress and want to have it without javascript, this is the reason why I did not use CollectionType.

To get this working I added a setter Method to Entity\User for "billingAddresses":

```
/**
     * Set billingAddresses
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     * 
     */
    public function setBillingAddresses(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        if($this->billingAddresses !== NULL and $this->billingAddresses->contains($billingAddress)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->addBillingAddress($billingAddress);
        return $this;
    }
```

In twig I render the fields like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.payment.user.billingAddresses) }}
```

When I submit the form, I got errors for all address form fields (e. g. for user.billingAddresses[0].line1) in symfony profiler and the also in `{{ form_errors(form) }}`, but my form fields of billingAddress are not labeled as having an error (normally error message of each field is returned directly by form field and not in `{{ form_errors(form) }}` and in twig form field template `form.vars.valid` is not set to "false").

So how could I got correct form handling with many-to-many property with my custom form type (AddressType)?

Thank you and best!

Comment: Why not using a collection type with 'allow_add' to false ?

And, your setter is wrong, setBillingAddresses (plural), parameter: billingAddress (singular). Rename it to addBillingAddress.

Comment: When I set 'allow_add' to false, how do I then render one set of form fields for 'billingAddress' without javascript?

Comment: Not sure I understood your problem. This is the twig if you have already a billing address or if you would like to create a new one:
`{% if form.payment.user.billingAddresses|length %}
        {{ form_row(form.payment.user.billingAddresses) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_row(form.payment.user.billingAddresses.vars.prototype)|replace({'__name__': '1'})|raw }}
    {% endif %}`
Does it help ?

Comment: This I still tried, but when I submit the form (with errors), the form fields are empty are submission and the fields are not labeled has invalid.

Comment: Have you the `@Assert\Valid` annotation on your property ?

Comment: Yes I have, the fields are validated, but after submission empty and do not get invalid value. If I submit all fields valid but one field invalid, the validators says the valid fields are valid, the invalid field is invalid, but the fields are all empty and no error message is shown by the field.

Comment: Do you have another idea? The validation seems to work, but there is a problem with the returned fields with `form_row(form.payment.user.billingAddresses.vars.prototype)|‌​replace({'__name__': '1'})|raw }}`.